Which regulator should I follow to comply with ADs?
If some component was manufactured by an American company and installed on Airbus aircraft operated by a Canadian-registered airline. Should the operator check American ADs, or they will be adomted by EASA or Canadian civil aviation authority?

Typically you need to follow the directives and regulations of whatever authority the aircraft is operating under.
In Canada that'd be Canadian authorities. If the aircraft were to be used internationally, it'd also be any country's authorities that the aircraft crossed and lands in.
Of course in most cases when it comes to ADs, national authorities will all enforce them, whichever one issues it (not counting authorities in backwater countries like Zimbadwe or Cambodia probably, if they even have authorities of their own and don't just simply follow the regulations of a larger neighbour country).

if AC and component are made by BAC, then AD must be followed FAA rules, if the AC fly to Europe, then EADAS rules must be followed also.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
